# How can I get the number of lines and each line text from TMP_InputField?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using TMP_InputField to type text. after typing and in some case also pressing enter to new line and keep typing some text I want to get all the text from the TMP_InputField but as lines.

```
public TMP_InputField notesInputField;
```

then

```
private void Start()
{
  EnumerateLines(notesInputField.text);
}
```

and

```
IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(TMP_Text text)
{
    // We use GetTextInfo because .textInfo is not always valid
    TMP_TextInfo textInfo = text.GetTextInfo(text.text);

    for (int i = 0; i < textInfo.lineCount; i++)
    {
        TMP_LineInfo line = textInfo.lineInfo[i];
        yield return text.text.Substring(line.firstCharacterIndex, line.characterCount);
    }
}
```

but getting error on the line

```
EnumerateLines(notesInputField.text);
```

because notesInputField is type of TMP_InputField and the method EnumerateLines should get TMP_Text.

How can I get then each line from TMP_InputField ?

Answer (score 0):

this is working:

```
private void Start()
{
  string[] lines = notesInputField.text.Split('\n');
  List<string> linesList = new List<string>(lines);
  foreach (string line in linesList)
  {
    // do any logic with the line
  }
}
```